# Validation error while uploading custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am getting this error while uploading signup policy.

> Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy
>   "B2C_1A_SIGNUP_WEB_SP" of tenant
>   "titanidaasdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com".DisableStrongPassword is required
>   in Technical Profile 'AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail' of policy
>   'B2C_1A_SignUp_Web_SP' for custom password complexity or legacy
>   password restriction with weak custom regular expression. Add
>   "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword" into PersistedClaim
>   "passwordPolicies"

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Hi @Gowtham N. Did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 9):

Because you are implementing a custom complexity, you must disable the built-in complexity, by setting the **passwordPolicies** claim to `DisableStrongPassword`.

This claim value can be set in either the relying party technical profile (i.e. if the custom complexity is applicable for a specific flow):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn"/>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword"/>
    </InputClaims>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Or the **AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail** technical profile (i.e. if the custom complexity is applicable for all flows):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword" />
   </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Also remember to add it to Technical Profile "AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" in order for the PasswordReset policy to work.

Comment: high checking in from 2023. i have this set both on my `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` and my ` SignUpOrSignin.xml` and i'm still getting the error: `DisableStrongPassword is required in Technical Profile 'AAD-WritePasswordAndFlipMigratedFlag' of policy 'B2C_1A_SeamlessMigration_signuporsignin' for custom password complexity or legacy password restriction with weak custom regular expression. Add "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword" into PersistedClaim "passwordPolicies"` any ideas?